# not able to group element with same name

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt, help out in order to write xsl for below xml pattern.
I want to group elements with same name under one tag. there can be multiple elements having same name such as Shapes, Devices etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Screen>
  <Shapes>
    <Triangle id="tri1">
    <color>red</color>
    <size>large</size>
    </Triangle>
  </Shapes>
  <Shapes>
    <Rectangle id="rec1">
      <color>blue</color>
      <size>medium</size>
    </Rectangle>
  </Shapes>
  <Device>
    <Name>peg</Name>
    <type>X11</type>
  </Device>
  <Device>
    <Name>peg1222</Name>
    <type>X11111</type>
  </Device>
  <Utilities>
    <Software>QT</Software>
    <Platform>Linux</Platform>
  </Utilities>
</Screen>
```

For above xml file, i am using below xsl file

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <Shapes>
        <xsl:copy-of select="Shapes/*"/>
      </Shapes>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='Shapes']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output is coming as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Screen>
    <Shapes>
        <Triangle id="tri1">
    <color>red</color>
    <size>large</size>
    </Triangle>
        <Rectangle id="rec1">
      <color>blue</color>
      <size>medium</size>
    </Rectangle>
    </Shapes>
    <Device>
    <Name>peg</Name>
    <type>X11</type>
  </Device>
    <Device>
    <Name>peg1222</Name>
    <type>X11111</type>
  </Device>
    <Utilities>
    <Software>QT</Software>
    <Platform>Linux</Platform>
  </Utilities>
</Screen>
```

But it is grouping based on Shapes only, i don't know how many elements with get repeated in XML (we might get another element as repeated).

Please let me know if we can just modify the above xsl to accommodate xml with dynamic element occurrence with same name.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, which uses a key to match child elements of `Screen` based on their names and grouping their children under single parent:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="elements" match="/Screen/*" use="name()"/>
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="*[count(. | key('elements', name())[1]) = 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('elements', name())/*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Using a key is a good approach. It is not clear to me what should happen to the `Device` elements, though. @Ravi should clarify this. (By the way, I'm glad to see your XSLT skills are ever improving!)

Comment: @Lingamurthy, I am having same doubt as Mathias mentioned above.

Comment: @RudramuniTP To be clear, I was not suggesting there is a problem with Lingamurthy's code. I am saying that the OP did not state clearly enough what should happen to `Device` elements.

Comment: @MathiasMüller Thanks for the compliment. You are right, we need more clarification of what's expected. I assumed this solution because of the following statement by Ravi _I want to group elements with same name under one tag_.